# JSON with collection item class Name

Tags: java, json, collections

I'm trying to write generic converter that will be able to convert **any** JSON into a valid XML. So I can't use any annotations on incoming model classes that were used to create JSON.

Let's say that someone uses following classes to create JSON

```java
class Wrapper {
    private List<Item> items;
}

class Item {
    private int id;
    private int name
}
```

The JSON would look like this:

```
{"Wrapper":{"items":[{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"B"}]}}
```

And I'm losing information about className Item

if I would use library like JSONObject, final XML would look like:

XML:

```
<Wrapper>
    <items><name>A</name><id>1</id></items>
    <items><name>B</name><id>2</id></items>
</Wrapper>
```

The XML is unfortunately in non deserializable format. It misses "Item" wrapper

The acceptable xml output should be something like:

```
<Wrapper>
    <items>
       <item>
         <name>A</name>
         <id>1</id>
       </item>
       <item>
          <name>B</name>
          <id>2</id>
       <item>
   </items>
</Wrapper>
```

Is there any way to serialize item className into JSON collection so that it could be used for proper XML element wrapping?

I know that I could get something like this using @JsonTypeInfo annotation, however I want to avoid modifying external classes that create JSON payload.

```
"Wrapper":{"items":[{"type":"TestDataBuilder$Item","id":1,"name":"A"},{"type":"TestDataBuilder$Item","id":2,"name":"B"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to achieve what you want (you can convert it to compact or readable XML depending on your needs) :

```js
const jsonObj = `{"Wrapper":{"items":[{"type":"TestDataBuilder$Item","id":1,"name":"A"},{"type":"TestDataBuilder$Item","id":2,"name":"B"}]}}`

const JSONtoXML = (json, compact = false) => {
    const EOL = compact ? '' : '\n'
    const SOL = compact ? '' : '  '

    const objToXML = obj => {
        let xmlContent = ''

        if (typeof obj === 'object')
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
                const value = obj[key]
                
                if (typeof value !== 'object')
                    return xmlContent += `${ SOL }<${ key }>${ value }</${ key }>${ EOL }`

                xmlContent += `<${ key }>${ EOL }`

                if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                    const itemName = key.endsWith('s') ? key.slice(0, -1) : key

                    value.forEach(e => {
                        xmlContent += `${ SOL }<${ itemName }>${ EOL + SOL }${ objToXML(e).split('\n').join(EOL + SOL) }</${ itemName }>${ EOL }`
                    })
                } else {
                    let valXml = objToXML(value)

                    if (!compact)
                        valXml = SOL + valXml.split('\n').join(EOL + SOL)

                    xmlContent += valXml + EOL
                }

                xmlContent += `</${ key }>`
            })

        else {
            xmlContent = obj.toString()
        }

        return xmlContent
    }

    return objToXML(JSON.parse(json))
}

console.log(JSONtoXML(jsonObj))

setTimeout(() => {}, 1e6)
```

Hope it helped you !